Context Provider does not rerender on custom hook state change
I have the following custom hook to manage state globally in my React app :
  export function useAromas() {
   const [state, setState] = useState<UseAromasState>({
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("custom hook rerendered because of state change");
  }, [state]);

  const apiUrl = new URL(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + "/aromas");

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    fetchAromas(signal);
    return () => controller.abort();
  }, []);

  const fetchAromas = (signal?: AbortSignal) => {
    setState((state) => ({ ...state, loading: true }));
    return customFetch<Aroma[]>({
      url: apiUrl,
      options: { method: "GET", signal },
    }).then((result) => {
      setState({ ...result, loading: false });
      return result.abortController;
     });
  };

  const refreshAromas = () => {
    console.log("refreshing aromas");
    fetchAromas();
  };

  const createAroma = (name: string, brand: Brand) => {
    const request = { name, brand };
    return customFetch<Aroma>({
      url: apiUrl,
      options: {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  const deleteAroma = (aromaId: Aroma["id"]): Promise<boolean> => {
    return customFetch({
      url: new URL(apiUrl.toString() + "/" + aromaId),
      options: {
        method: "DELETE",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("received delete response : ");
        console.log(response);
        refreshAromas();
        return response.data as boolean;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      });
  };
  const returnValue = { ...state, refreshAromas, createAroma, deleteAroma };
  console.log(" new return value from useAromas");
  console.log(returnValue);
  return returnValue;
}

I have a context provider defined as follow :
 export const AromasProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) 
  => {
  const context = useAromas();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AromasProvider rerendered");
  }, [context]);

  
  console.log("AromasProvider provides ");
  console.log(context);
  return (
    <AromasContext.Provider value={context}>{children} 
 </AromasContext.Provider>
  );
 };

My problem is that on state change the provider does not rerender and hence does not propagate state change to consumers.
Logging both the return value of useAromas, and useEffect with a dependancy on context in the context provider shows that despite the state change, the provider does not rerender.
I have the confirmation that the state is not propagated to consumer, the following consumer logs show me that the context does not reflex state change :
export function useAromasContext() {
    const aromasContext = useContext(AromasContext);
    console.log("context provided is ");
    console.log(aromasContext);
  if (!aromasContext)
    throw new Error("[useAromasContext ERROR] No AromasContext Provider found");

  return aromasContext;
}

I have tried to destructure the result of useAromas() in the context provider to make sure I have new objects with new references but it didn't change anything.
export const AromasProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { refreshAromas, data, createAroma, deleteAroma, error, loading } =
    useAromas();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AromasProvider rerendered");
  }, [data]);

  const context = {
    refreshAromas,
    data,
    createAroma,
    deleteAroma,
    error,
    loading,
  };
  console.log("AromasProvider provides ");
  console.log(context);
  return (
    <AromasContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AromasContext.Provider>
  );
};

I went as far as rewriting the hook and context after @LinDu test showing that this code should work.
My hook has 2 function to createAroma and deleteAroma they look as follow :
 function deleteAroma(aromaId: string) {
    const deleteUrl = new URL(apiUrl + "/" + aromaId);

    customFetch({ url: deleteUrl, options: { method: "DELETE" } }).then(() =>
      fetchAromas()
    );
  }

  function createAroma(aromaName: string, brand: Brand) {
    const payload = { name: aromaName, brand };

    customFetch({
      url: apiUrl,
      options: {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      },
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log("[CREATED NEW AROMA] " + result.data);
      fetchAromas();
    });
  }

To refresh data after a successfull request they both call fetchAromas defined as follow :
 const fetchAromas = () => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    customFetch<Aroma[]>({
      url: apiUrl,
      options: { method: "GET", signal },
    }).then((result) => {
      setState((state) => {
        console.log("[FETCHED NEW AROMAS AND SETTING STATE]");
        console.log(result.data?.length);
        return { ...state, aromas: result.data ?? [] };
      });
    });

    return () => controller.abort();
  };

What baffles me is that when a consumer calls deleteAroma everything is perfectly fine : AromasProvider rerenders and the updated state is reflected in consumers.
But when calling fetchAromas it just does not work. Despite logging shows the retrieved data confirm the request success and the state is changed AromasProvider does not rerender and hence context is not propagated.
I dont know how it is possible has bot function call the exact same fetchAromas in their callback, and this function logs show it is updating state in both cases.
Here is what the provider and context look like :
 export const AromasContext = createContext<ReturnType<typeof useAromas>>({
  aromas: [],
  createAroma: () => {
    "createAroma is NOT DEFINED in CONTEXT";
  },
  deleteAroma: () => {
    "creteAroma is NOT DEFINED in CONTEXT";
  },
});

export const AromasProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const contextValue = useAromas();
  console.log("[AROMAS PROVIDER]contextValue provided : ");
  console.log(contextValue);
  return (
    <AromasContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AromasContext.Provider>
  );
};

I am totally out of ideas as where to look for possible cause...

Can't reproduce. It works fine, see this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-akdrt9?file=src%2FApp.tsx

oh, thanks, but that's disappointing, I am using React Router  could it be linked to it  ?

hmm it seems you example is not working at all, there are several import errors and i dont see how you are testing the behavior, there is nothing that changes the state, either through user interaction nor programmatically. And nothing is logged in the terminal. Do I miss something ?

I can see the consumer component gets the updated context by the logs. The initial context data is [], the updated context data is [1,2,3]

ok my bad found it

still the problem is not solved, I am updating my question with further tests

@Zach can you create an example with the full code?

After creating to new mock components for furthing testing i found that the cause was the most stupid mistake :
The cause whas that the consumer calling createAroma was actually calling the useAromas hook directly instead of using it through context by calling useAromasContext.
